# How to fetch which sim card received SMS in flutter?

Tags: flutter, sms, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test, flutter-localizations

Currently I am fetching the SMS details using sms package in flutter. But I am not able to get the receiver's number using that package.

1. I want to know How I can get those receiver's details?
2. If not, I am trying to get which sim card has received the sms in mobile and fetch the sim card number. How can I achieve this?

Please help, I have been trying to implement it for a long time, but had no luck... If you need further more info, do let me know.

Comment: Did you try this package https://pub.dev/packages/telephony

Comment: yeah, It will not give you the receiver number, It will only give you sender address...

Comment: any success in this?